# Término en español para "virtue signaling"

Tags: traducción, modismos

Recién escuché esta expresión en inglés. ¿Saben si existe alguna expresión similar en español? No logro encontrar nada en internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alardeo_moral)

> El alardeo de la virtud (también llamado postureo ético; en inglés *virtue signalling*, literalmente señalización de virtud) es la excesiva exhibición de determinados valores con la intención de comunicar el buen carácter propio.

Algo muy habitual en redes sociales, yo lo suelo llamar *falsa moral*. En España se utiliza mucho la palabra *postureo*. Me gusta particularmente la definición del diccionario [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/virtue-signalling):

> Virtue signalling is the popular modern habit of indicating that one has virtue merely by expressing disgust or favour for certain political ideas or cultural happenings.

Answer (score 0):

*que tal?*

---

Entiendo que la palabra *postureo*, por si sola no basta, ya que por *postureo* se entiende un comportamiento poco natural de una persona que se esfuerza por dar una imagen pública para agradar ó conseguir la aprobación de otras personas. Sin embargo, el "virtue signaling" es *interpretado* como "*Postureo ético*", y el matiz es importante, *no solo postureo*, sino aquello que también es *ético*, y por tanto incluye una conducta moral, es decir, aquello que una parte de la sociedad entiende de como deberían actuar o comportarse los individuos en determinadas ocasiones ó ante determinadas ideas. No solo es una cuestión de imagen o quedar bien, sino de decencia y en este caso, de cumplir lo que se dice o se promete.

- Para más información, la cuestión surgió en la televisión norteamericana, en un programa de debate donde hablaban de una especie de plan verde de la congresista por Nueva York del partido demócrata, Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez, que trataba temas de política energética. El presentador lo calificó de discurso hueco, o algo sin relevancia.
  La cuestión;

  `In reading this document...Isn't it just one big form of "virtue signalling"? It would be nice...!, but it doesn't have any details of how we would get there."`

Traducción;

*Al leer este documento... ¿No es solo una gran forma de "señalización de la virtud"? ¡Sería bueno…!, pero no tiene ningún detalle de cómo llegaríamos ahí.*

---

Espero haya ayudado. Saludos.
Diego.

Answer (score 0):

No seria 'el buenismo' lo mas aproximado a 'virtue signalling' en español?

Comment: Virtue signalling is not el buenisimo

Comment: @mdewey the answer proposes "buenismo", not "buenísimo". Still not an exact match, but somewhat closer and worth a thought.